# String representation in Class

Tags: python, class, oop

I understand the following classes will show as follows:

```
class ClubHead(ABC):
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self._loft:.1f},{self._weight}'
```

```
class WoodHead(ClubHead):
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Wood,{super().__str__()},{self._size}'
```

Wood,9.0,200,445

```
class IronHead(ClubHead):
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Iron,{super().__str__()},{self._material}'
```

Iron,37.0,250,Cast

```
class PutterHead(ClubHead):
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Putter,{super().__str__()},{self._style}'
```

Putter,3.0,380,Blade

Is it possible to present the `__str__(self)` in the Club class as such:

3-Hybrid,20.5,250,220

without the Wood, Iron or Putter reflected?

```
class Club:
    def __init__(self, label, head):
        self._label = label.upper()
        self._head = head

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self._label},{self._head}'
```

Based on the above code, it will show 3-Hybrid, Wood, 20.5,250,220 instead.

Comment: Where does `20.5,250,220` come from?

Comment: Is `head` a `ClubHead` instance?

Comment: yes. head refers to ClubHead instance.

Answer (score 0):

Define a different method that returns all the parameters other than the head type, and implement it in all the classes.

```
class ClubHead(ABC):
    def params(self):
        return [self._loft, self._weight]

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.label},{','.join(self.params)}'

class WoodHead(ClubHead):
    label = 'Wood'
    def params(self):
        return super().params() + [self._size]

class IronHead(ClubHead):
    label = 'Iron'
    def params(self):
        return super().params() + [self._material]

class PutterHead(ClubHead):
    label = 'Putter'
    def params(self):
        return super().params() + [self._style]

class Club:
    def __init__(self, label, head):
        self._label = label.upper()
        self._head = head

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self._label},{','.join(self._head.params()}'
```